# What is the "sensible default" for the Kest function of the spatstat package?

Tags: spatial, point-process, ripley-k, spatstat

I'm reading the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatstat/spatstat.pdf) on the `Kest` function (page 731) from the [spatstat](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatstat/index.html) package.

For the argument $r$, that is the "*Vector of values for the argument $r$ at which $K(r)$ should be evaluated*", it states that:

> Users are advised *not* to specify this argument; there is a sensible default.

I'm interested in knowing how this argument is specified. I went to look at the [source](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat/blob/master/R/Kest.R) for this function but I'm not an expert on `R` (I write in `Python`) and I can't decipher how it is calculated.

I know that the piece of code that determines this is here:

```
  rmaxdefault <- rmax %orifnull% rmax.rule("K", W, lambda)
  if(is.infinite(rmaxdefault)) rmaxdefault <- diameter(W)
  breaks <- handle.r.b.args(r, breaks, W, rmaxdefault=rmaxdefault)
  r <- breaks$r
  rmax <- breaks$max

  (...)

  # recommended range of r values
  alim <- c(0, min(rmax, rmaxdefault))
```

Assuming `rmax=NULL` (the default) and a rectangular window, could you explain how the final vector `alim` is obtained?

Comment: Just realized that this has been asked before over at SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14330415/1391441

Comment: It's not necessarily a problem that this is a duplicate of a question *on another site*. If you want to delete this, you can. Alternatively, you can answer it yourself & reference the SO thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in `spatstat`'s [FAQ](http://spatstat.org/FAQ.html):

> 11. How are the r values determined in Kest(X) ?
>
> The default r values for Kest are computed as follows:
>
> 1. The maximum r value is computed by the function 'rmax.rule', `rmax \<- rmax.rule("K", W, lambda)` where `W` is the window containing the data,
>    and lambda is the average density of points per unit area. Currently
>    this rule takes the minimum of
>
>    - Ripley’s rule of thumb: rmax = one quarter of the smallest side of the enclosing rectangle
>    - large sample
>      rule: `rmax = sqrt(1000/(pi \* lambda))`
> 2. r values are equally spaced
>    from 0 to rmax with step value `eps`. If eps is not specified, then
>    `eps = rmax/512` so that there are 513 values or 512 intervals.
>
> You can always override the `r` values if you need to.

This means that, for a window of (length,width)=[0,1]x[0,1] (ie: `A=1`) and assuming that the number of points is `N` , the array of radii values is obtained as follows (in pseudo-code):

```
rho = N / A  # density
thumb = A / 4 # rule of thumb
large = sqrt(1000 / (pi * rho)) # rule of large numbers
rmax = min(thumb, large)
```

Hence for `N<~5000` the array of radii will be an equal-spaced segmentation of the range [0, 0.25] in 512 intervals.

---

This was also asked over at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14330415/1391441).